# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable is not defined

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have this problem when I try to

`getDefinitionByName('some_var_by_class_linkage')`.

But I have such variable in my .swf file. And it gets from .swf file. But sometimes this error occurs. I read a lot about it, but don't finded appropriate solution for me. What can it be?

Here is some detailed explanation of my problem with screenshot.  http://vzaar.com/help/discussions/problems/580-actionscript-error-referenceerror-error-1065-variable-circle_cut_5-is-not-defined

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(name:String):Object
>
> Returns a reference to the class object of the class specified by the
>   name parameter.
>
> Parameters: name The name of a class.
>
> Returns: Returns a reference to the class object of the class
>   specified by the name parameter.

[1.Refer this](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2010/03/14/getdefinitionbyname-error-variable-is-not-defined/)
[2.Refer this](http://flashvideotrainingsource.com/featured_post/hints-and-tips/quick-tip-understanding-getdefinitionbyname)

Answer (score 2):

Might be because you didn't check "Export on frame 1" in the MovieClip properties.. (I assume it is a MovieClip you made in you in your Library that you wish to use in your Actionscript?)

Comment: No. Export on frame 1 is setted